# How do I include this variable inside this class?

Tags: php, class

my code looks like something like this:

```
require_once('class.php')


$test = "test"

class Issue extends class {

  var $value = $test;

  //more stuff included in this class

}
```

it works when var $value = "test";
but I really need it to take value that is outside the class, I tried using global but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should pass your var through the constructor.

Comment: You cannot use `class` word as classname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a parameter of your class constructor:

```
require_once('class.php')

$test = "test";

class Issue extends class {

  public $value;

  public function __construct($test) {
    $this->value = $test;
  }
}
```

If `Issue::value` is public you can also just assign it's value directly:

```
$issue = new Issue();
$issue->value = $test;
```

You can also create helper methods (i.e. setters) or use magic methods to populate this value as well.

FYI, using `var` in classes in obsolete and has been for quite some time. i recommend getting up to speed with PHP current syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about var I'm still new-ish to PHP and the library I am working with used it.